# Have the header row for the table starting from the second page

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, table-of-contents, caption, title

I am dealing with making some tables which are extended to multiple pages and I want to have the table title on each page.

If I add it as the table name, it will show up in the table of contents multiple times which is not desired. Then, if I add a header row it will be fine except that it also shows up in the first page (as a duplicate, because I already have the title there).

Is there a way to have the header row on all pages of a table except the first one. Or is there a way to have the title for all pages but show it once in the table of content?

p.s. I am open to use/familiar with VBA. IF you have hints to do it using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Header Row of the table, set the Style Name to one that will appear in your Table of Contents. for example, Heading 1 or Heading 2.

The Table Name will not appear multiple times in your TOC (Table of Contents) because the table header row is not physically in the subsequent pages of the document. It is only an autogenerated reference. You cannot alter it, cut it, etc.

Here is proof:

[image]

Another approach, suggested by Cybernetic-nomad in the comments, would look like the following:

[image]

The row labeled "Main Header" in this example is actually a separate table. The Sub Header table row will repeat.

Comment: Then I will have it twice on the first page. Because caption (which will be appearing in TOC) is on the first page and then the header row is also on the first page.

Comment: Why are you putting Captions in the TOC? They should be in a Table of Figures. And BTW ... Where in your question do you mention that you are using Captions in the TOC?

Comment: By caption I meant the table name (i.e. title (consider it like a subsection name), e.g. `Table 2. Values of something`). sorry about using the wrong terminology. So if you have table title after each page break they will also show up in TOC. What I essentially wanna do, as stated in the Q is that have the title only on the first page, and repeat it on the second page onward.

Comment: Use one table for the first page, then another for all subsequent pages with the desired table header?

Comment: Rich and @cybernetic.nomad thank you both. I moved toward using `latex` as this for whatever reason was not working in that document but testing these in a fresh session of word was a valid solution. Cheers.